# Как добавить сразу несколько слайдеров Swiper на сайте для табов?

Tags: javascript, swiper, слайдер

У меня есть таб с разными категориями для портфолио, и в каждый из них нужно добавить свой слайдер с своими работами.
Можно ли это сделать не дублируя сразу весь код JS(var swiper = new Swiper) для каждого отдельного слайдера?

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".slider", {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  init: false,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },

  breakpoints: {
    320: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
    },
    990: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
    },
    991: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
    },
  },

});

swiper.on("slideChange afterInit init", function () {
  let currentSlide = this.activeIndex + 1;
  document.querySelector('.counter').innerHTML = `
  <span class="counter__current">
  ${currentSlide < 10 ? '0' + currentSlide : currentSlide}
  </span>  
  <span class="counter__total">
    /${this.slides.length}
  </span>`;
});

swiper.init();
```

```
<div class="services__content">

    <ul class="tabs" id="portfolio">
        <li class="active"><a>Сайты</a></li>
        <li><a>SMM</a></li>
        <li><a>Контекст</a></li>
        <li><a>Брендинг</a></li>
        <li><a>Презентация</a></li>
        <li><a>Полиграфия</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab_container">
    
        <div class="tab_content active"> <!-- Сайты -->

            <div class="slider__wrapper">

                <div class="swiper slider"> <!-- Слайдер -->
        
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

                        <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

                 <div class="swiper__mobile">
                    <div class="counter"></div>
                     <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                 </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="tab_content"></div> <!-- SMM -->

        <div class="tab_content"></div> <!-- Контекст -->

        <div class="tab_content"></div> <!-- Брендинг -->

        <div class="tab_content"></div> <!-- Презентация -->

        <div class="tab_content"></div> <!-- Полиграфия -->
 
    </div>

</div>
```

```
$('.services__content').each(function(){

    let tabTabs = $(this).find('ul.tabs li');
    let tabItems = $(this).find('.tab_content').hide();
    $(".tab_container .tab_content.active").show();

    tabTabs.each(function(i){
      $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').show();
        tabTabs.not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(tabItems[i]).addClass('active').show();
        tabItems.not(tabItems[i]).removeClass('active').hide();
      });
    });
    
});
```

Comment: В чём проблема создать ф-ию с нужными аргументами вызывать сколько и где надо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
let swipers = document.querySelectorAll(".slider"); //Находим все слайдеры в tab'ах

swipers.forEach(value => {
  let swiper = new Swiper(value, {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    init: false,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: value.querySelector('.swiper-button-next'), //инициализируем кнопки управления у ДАННОГО слайдера через поиск querySelector()
      prevEl: value.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev'), //инициализируем кнопки управления у ДАННОГО слайдера через поиск querySelector()
    },

    pagination: {
      el: value.querySelector(".swiper-pagination"), //инициализируем пагиницию у ДАННОГО слайдера через поиск querySelector()
      clickable: true,
    },

    breakpoints: {
      320: {
        slidesPerView: 1,
      },
      990: {
        slidesPerView: 1,
      },
      991: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
      },
    },
    observer: true,
    observerParents: true
  });

  swiper.on("slideChange afterInit init", function() {
    let currentSlide = this.activeIndex + 1;
    value.querySelector('.counter').innerHTML = `
  <span class="counter__current">
  ${currentSlide < 10 ? '0' + currentSlide : currentSlide}
  </span>  
  <span class="counter__total">
    /${this.slides.length}
  </span>`;
  });

  swiper.init();
});

$('.services__content').each(function() {

  let tabTabs = $(this).find('ul.tabs li');
  let tabItems = $(this).find('.tab_content').hide();
  $(".tab_container .tab_content.active").show();

  tabTabs.each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('active').show();
      tabTabs.not(this).removeClass('active');
      $(tabItems[i]).addClass('active').show();
      tabItems.not(tabItems[i]).removeClass('active').hide();
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="services__content">

  <ul class="tabs" id="portfolio">
    <li class="active"><a>Сайты</a></li>
    <li><a>SMM</a></li>
    <li><a>Контекст</a></li>
    <li><a>Брендинг</a></li>
    <li><a>Презентация</a></li>
    <li><a>Полиграфия</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab_container">

    <div class="tab_content active">
      <!-- Сайты -->

      <div class="slider__wrapper">

        <div class="swiper slider">
          <!-- Слайдер -->

          <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд</div>

          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

          <div class="swiper__mobile">
            <div class="counter"></div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="tab_content">
      <!-- Сайты -->

      <div class="slider__wrapper">

        <div class="swiper slider">
          <!-- Слайдер -->

          <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 2</div>

          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

          <div class="swiper__mobile">
            <div class="counter"></div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SMM -->

    <div class="tab_content">
      <!-- Сайты -->

      <div class="slider__wrapper">

        <div class="swiper slider">
          <!-- Слайдер -->

          <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 3</div>

          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

          <div class="swiper__mobile">
            <div class="counter"></div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Контекст -->

    <div class="tab_content">
      <!-- Сайты -->

      <div class="slider__wrapper">

        <div class="swiper slider">
          <!-- Слайдер -->

          <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 4</div>

          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

          <div class="swiper__mobile">
            <div class="counter"></div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Брендинг -->

    <div class="tab_content">
      <!-- Сайты -->

      <div class="slider__wrapper">

        <div class="swiper slider">
          <!-- Слайдер -->

          <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 5</div>

          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

          <div class="swiper__mobile">
            <div class="counter"></div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Презентация -->

    <div class="tab_content">
      <!-- Сайты -->

      <div class="slider__wrapper">

        <div class="swiper slider">
          <!-- Слайдер -->

          <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Слайд 6</div>

          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

          <div class="swiper__mobile">
            <div class="counter"></div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Полиграфия -->

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137510/discussion-on-answer-by-pr0gramm1st------swipe).